# how to get the data from file and set to text Area in vaadin

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I have Created One project.Buta i get data in console i want set data to textarea

```
    File[] F=File.listFiles();

    for (File File1:F) {
        FileInputStream fstream = null;
        String strLine ;
        try {
            fstream = new FileInputStream(File1);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
                System.out.println (strLine);
            String str=strLine;

            final TextArea txt=new TextArea(str);

            layout.addComponents(txt); 
            //br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must accumulate the read lines, so you can then later on add it to the text area.
You might consider what to do with line breaks, currently they just get sorted out of the final string/text.

```
for (File File1:F) 
{
    FileInputStream fstream = null;
    String strLine;
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    try 
    {
        fstream = new FileInputStream(File1);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
        {
            System.out.println (strLine);
            sb.append(str);
        }
        final TextArea txt=new TextArea(sb.toString());

        layout.addComponents(txt); 
        //br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct answers should be marked as answers, @lokeshmenta.